# Extending global.asax in Umbraco 4.7 for dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, umbraco

Im using umbraco v 4.7.1 (Assembly version: 1.0.4281.20201) and have a project where I must extend the global.asax file.

Please not the following

- I have tried this, http://blog.mattbrailsford.com/2010/07/11/registering-an-application-start-event-handler-in-umbraco/, didn't work in 4.7
- it is Global.asax I need to extend since I'm working with dependency injection
- I cannot delete the App_global.asax.dll file (as some may suggest) since it will regenerate everytime I restart or rebuild my project

Here is my implementation,

```
using Project.Umbraco.DependencyInjection;
using Project.Umbraco.IoC;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using umbraco;

namespace Project.Umbraco.App_Start
{
    public class MyGlobal : Global, IContainerAccessor
    {
        /// 

        /// Returns the IoC container
        /// IContainerAccessor
        /// 

        public IUnityContainer Container
        {
            get
            {
                return MvcUnityContainer.Instance.Container;
            }
        }

        protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.Application_Start(sender, e);
            Debug.WriteLine("Application start");
        }

        protected override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
            Debug.WriteLine("Application start");
        }
        //protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        //protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        //protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        //protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        //protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
    }
}
```

The implementation seems as if should work, maybe I've just placed this in the wrong namespace or something?

Thanks for any help

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Umbraco 4.8.0 and onwards, the App_global.asax.dll is no longer needed, so you might want to consider upgrading to a newer version.

In 4.7 though, you could simply use the PreApplicationStart method by creating a class that looks a little something like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;
using CustomerName.Extensions;

[assembly: System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppStart), "PreStart")]
namespace CustomerName.Extensions
{
    public static class AppStart
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of defining WebAPI routes, you could insert your DI code.

Comment: Thanks, I will move this project to 4.9 in the near feature, I've done some laborations with PreApplicationStart and got it working. It does however not allow me to inject my IUnityContainer into the Context!

Comment: I have never worked with Unity so I can't really comment on it, but make sure to Google [PreApplicationStartMethod iUnityContainer][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=PreApplicationStartMethod%20iUnityContainer#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=PreApplicationStartMethod%20iUnityContainer&oq=PreApplicationStartMethod%20iUnityContainer&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.2149.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.ltNDAtqFZxk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=515062ea71d68403&biw=1680&bih=949